# Is the i18n submodule Taxonomy Translation necessary at all?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am developing a multilingual site. The client enters the content, which is classified in taxonomies (vocabulary terms), which are translated for each language. My client has asked me if it was not better to assign a category in native language, and the system could translate later. I have replied that it is better to assign a different language node a translated term, using Taxonomy Translation capability, as later the search in the Views, etc., the friendly URLs, etc., are better designed. For example, if I have social-networks and redes-sociales (Spanish for social-networks) as a filter, I can better filter using a simple conceptual filter.
Do you think this is the correct approach ? The proposal of the client seemed reasonable, but there were many pitfalls and complicated code behind of it.